# Linked reference to a Github milestone in a tag or commit message

Tags: github, tags, milestone

I use to add issue numbers in Git commits, to let Github make links from commits to issues and from issues to commits.

**Is it also possible to do the same in tag messages towards milestones?**

In my project, each release has a tag, and each release consists of a number of issues that are grouped in a milestone. Therefore a linked reference from the tag message to the milestone would be very useful.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As you can see on the [Github Help Pages](https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/) about possible references, there is no auto-linking for milestones as of today.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the correct spot in the Github Help Pages.

Comment: Still no auto linking for milestones based  on the info in the linked help Article called "Autolinked references and URLs" , https://help.github.com/articles/autolinked-references-and-urls/ found on the mentioned help page

Comment: By any chance if you are using GitLab then you can see this feature. https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/markdown.html#special-gitlab-references